# Invertibility of a function

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, differential-geometry, manifolds

S is a surface in $\mathbb{R}^{3}$ parameterized by a function $f:S\rightarrow(a,b)^{2}\subset\mathbb{R}^{2}$

$F$ is the function defined by:

$F:T^{1}S\rightarrow(a,b)^{2}\times S^{1}$ ($T^{1}S$ is the unit
tangent bundle of $S,$ and $S^{1}$ is the unit circle)

$F(x,s)=(f(x),\dfrac{Tf(x).s}{\mid Tf(x).s\mid}$) ($Tf(x)$ is the
tangent map)

Is $F$ a bijection ?

If yes, how to compute $F^{-1}$ ?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming $f$ is a bijection, $f$ and $f^{-1}$ are differentiable, and $\det(Tf(x)) \neq 0$ for any $x$, then $F$ is a bijection.  The inverse formula would be

$F^{-1} (y, w) = (f^{-1}(y), \frac{Tf^{-1}(y).w}{|Tf^{-1}(y).w|})$

Applying $F$ to this directly gives back the identity.  The main point is that

$Tf(x)^{-1} = Tf^{-1}(f(x))$

Comment: $Tf(x)$  is not a square matrix ?

Comment: So what is the sense of $det(Tf(x))$ ?

Comment: Tf(x) is a mapping from a 2-dimensional space to a 2-dimensional space, and so if you chose basis vectors for each subspace it would be a square matrix.

Comment: The matrix of  $Tf(x)$ is the Jacobian matrix of $f$, which is a mapping
from $S\subset\mathbb{R}^{3}$ to an open set of $\mathbb{R}^{2}$
. So it is a $2\times3$ matrix.

Comment: Is f a mapping from an open set around S to $(a,b)$?  I'm assuming $S$ is a 2-dimensional manifold.  You cannot take the Jacobian of $f$ at $x\in S$ unless $f$ is defined in an open neighborhood (in $\mathbb{R}^3$) of $x$.  Normally the tangent map at a point refers to the linear map from the tangent space of x to the tangent space of f(x), both of which are 2-d.

Comment: Ok, let's consider that S is an open subset of ${R}^{3}$. If I cannot use the Jacobian, how do I compute $Tf^{-1}(f(x))$ ? Maybe it is better, I don't know, to see a tangent vector as a derivative of a curve:
$Tf(x).s=Tf(x).\gamma'(0)=(f\circ\gamma)'(0)$, with $\gamma(t)$
a curve on $S$ and $\gamma(0)=x$ and $\gamma'(0)=s.$ With that,
how do I compute my inverse ?

Comment: By the way, do we have here  $Tf(x).s=Jacobian(f)(x)\times s$ ?

Comment: Take an example.  Let $S$ be the surface which is the image of $g(x,y) = (x,y,3x)$ from $0<x<2$, and $0<y<2$.  Parameterize it with $f(x,y,3x) = (x/2,y/2)$, so $(a,b)^2=(0,1)^2$.  Note that $f$ is only defined on a 2-d object, so it has no derivative in, say, the z-direction.  Take $p = (1,1,3)$ a point on $S$.  The tangent space at $p$ is spanned by the vectors $(1,0,3)_p$ and $(0,1,0)_p$, and according to this arbitrarily chosen basis, $Tf(p) = [1/2,0;0,1/2]$, assuming you're thinking in terms of the standard basis on $(a,b)^2$.  The explicit matrix will depend on the bases you...

Comment: ...choose.  The norms in this case for the map $F$ will need to be figured out, and their explicit formulas will depend on the bases.

Comment: If $\gamma:$$J\subset\mathbb{R}$ is a curve on $S$ so that $\gamma(0)=x$
and $\gamma'(0)=s$ then, if I am not wrong, $Tf(x).s=(f\circ\gamma)'(0)=f'(\gamma(0)\circ\gamma'(0)=Jacobian(f)(x)\times p$
???

And, as you wrote that $(Tf(x))^{-1}=Tf^{-1}(f(x)$ , I suppose that,
with the function $G$ defined by: $G(x,p)=Tf(x).p$ , we have: 

$G^{-1}(y,w)=Tf^{-1}(y).w=(f^{-1}\circ\zeta)'(0)=(f^{-1})'(\zeta(0))\circ\zeta'(0)=Jacobian(f^{-1})(f(x)\times w,$

Comment: with $\zeta$ a curve on $f(S)$ , like for $\gamma$ , so that $\zeta(0)=y$
and $\zeta'(0)=w.$

I need a way to compute explicitely the values of $G$ , that is why
I am trying to use matrices. Is my solution correct ?